# Convergence of a nice serie

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

For which value of $a>0$ and $b>0$ does $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{a^n2^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^{\sqrt{n}}+b^n}$$ converge?

Obviously it does not when $b<1$, but i don't have any answer otherwise.

Comment: It does when $b$ and $a$ are both less than $1$. You probably meant when $a\lt 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following cases:

1. $b>1$. Then $2^{\sqrt n}/b^n\to 0$ and we have 
   $$\frac{a^n2^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^{\sqrt{n}}+b^n}=\left(\frac ab\right)^n2^{\sqrt n}\frac 1{1+2^{\sqrt n}/b^n}.$$
   The series $\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{a^n2^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^{\sqrt{n}}+b^n}$ is thus convergent when $a\lt b$ and divergent if $a\geqslant b$.

   2. $b=1$: then it converges if and only if $a\lt 1$.
   3. $b<1$. Since $b^n2^{-\sqrt n}\to 0$, we have 
      $$\frac{a^n2^{\sqrt{n}}}{2^{\sqrt{n}}+b^n}=a^n\frac{1}{1+b^n2^{-\sqrt n}},$$
      we get the convergence if and only if $a\lt 1$.

Comment: ...thanks :)...